# Run-time Error 424 Object Required

Tags: vba, outlook

Im writing a macro for outlook 2010. I get the error on the for each loop even the first time and oFolder does contain a folder.
BTW, SaveAttachments runs correctly the first time its just the second time it bombs.

```
Public Sub processFolder()

    Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Dim oParent As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim oFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim FolderName As String

    Set objInbox = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)        

    SaveAttachments (objInbox)


    If (objInbox.Folders.Count > 0) Then
        For Each oFolder In objInbox.Folders
            SaveAttachments (oFolder)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Sub SaveAttachments(ByVal oParent As Outlook.MAPIFolder)

```
'Declaration
Dim myItems, myItem, myAttachments, myAttachment As Object
Dim myOrt As String
Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application

myOrt = "C:\attachments"

On Error Resume Next

'for all items do...
For Each myItem In oParent.Items

    'point on attachments
    Set myAttachments = myItem.Attachments

    'if there are some...
    If myAttachments.Count > 0 Then

        'add remark to message text
        myItem.Body = myItem.Body & vbCrLf & _
            "Removed Attachments:" & vbCrLf

        'for all attachments do...
        For i = 1 To myAttachments.Count

            'save them to destination
            myAttachments(i).SaveAsFile myOrt & _
                myAttachments(i).DisplayName

            'add name and destination to message text
            myItem.Body = myItem.Body & _
                "File: " & myOrt & _
                myAttachments(i).DisplayName & vbCrLf

        Next i

        'for all attachments do...
        While myAttachments.Count > 0

            'remove it (use this method in Outlook XP)
            'myAttachments.Remove 1

            'remove it (use this method in Outlook 2000)
            myAttachments(1).Delete

        Wend

        'save item without attachments
        myItem.Save
    End If

Next

'free variables
Set myItems = Nothing
Set myItem = Nothing
Set myAttachments = Nothing
Set myAttachment = Nothing
Set myOlApp = Nothing
Set myOlExp = Nothing
Set myOlSel = Nothing
```

End Sub

Comment: Which line of you code raises that error? What is the SaveAttachments sub?

Comment: For Each oFolder In objInbox.Folders
            **SaveAttachments (oFolder)**
        Next

Comment: When you step through the code, which object is null?

Comment: Thats what I dont get. oFolder is not null when saveAttachments is called.

Comment: So can you step through the code?

Answer (score 1):

You have mixed and matched the method of calling SaveAttachments

Choose one or the other

```
Call SaveAttachments(objInbox)  ' <--- Call requires brackets

SaveAttachments objInbox        ' <--- No brackets

SaveAttachments oFolder         ' <--- No brackets
```